# What is the procedure to publish a WMS using Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, google-earth

I wanted to be able to load a network connection in Google Earth (or Google Maps) to display daily updated maps using Geoserver. I want something very simple but I have never published web maps before.

Can anyone explain the steps required to do this?

---

Update:

Meanwhile i managed to learn most part of it. Now i only need to know how to perform spatial analysis and publish the results all automatically.

Comment: can you clarify your question? it's not clear if you want help loading data into GeoServer or in how to get a KML file back out of GeoServer? or something else completely

Comment: I wanted to know all the steps to do this from scratch. Meanwhile i managed to learn most part of it. Now i only need to know how to perform spatial analysis and publish the results all automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure exactly what the question is but.. If you have Geoserver up and running, the easiest step is to use the sample view feature to view your wms data.  Copy and paste the address into the network link in Google Earth.
You can also customize the display in google earth with simple xml files placed in the data folders.  Search the Geoserver help, there are some nice tutorials there.